# Reading compressed json file in apache beam dataframe

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

It looks like beam dataframe  support reading a compressed json file [apache_beam.dataframe.io.read_json](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.47.0/apache_beam.dataframe.io.html#apache_beam.dataframe.io.read_json)

However, when I am trying to read a file through the code:

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_json,
beam_df = pipeline | read_json(path=input_file, lines=True, compression_type="gzip")
```

It's throwing an error:

```
AttributeError: 'CompressedFile' object has no attribute 'writable'
```

Is my implementation correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file with gzip and then directly read the resulting file or have Pandas read the file.

**First Approach:**

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv
with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    df = pd.read_json(f, lines=True)
```

**Second Approach:**

Where `pd.read_json` will infer the compression format based on the file name and your file ends with .gz, you can write it as:

```
df = pd.read_json(file_path)
```